# What are the hammers for in Kid Icarus Myths and Monsters?

Tags: kid-icarus-myths-monsters

I have collected a bunch of hammers in my travels, which is all well and good, but I really have no idea what I am supposed to do with them.

What are they for? How do they work?

Answer (score 3):

> Hammers are sold for 20 Hearts here unless Pit is buying from a
>   merchant in a Fortress, where they cost 50 instead.

Got it word for word from http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Mallet They are consumable items that can be used to inflict grievous damage upon foes. (Up to lvl 5)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! +1 for the info & update; but imho the question was asking what hammers *do* (ie. the part about damage & centurions) - though @AshleyNunn is the best judge of that.